# Streaming audio through web socket on GCS

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have created a Google Cloud Speech 2 Text php application that works flawlessly and I want to create a live decode on the same application.
The application should grab the microphone audio from the users web browser and transfer it through web socket (or socket.io) to the server and send in real time the transcriptions back to the web page.
I have checked the samples of Google on transcribing a streaming audio feed and didn't understood how to give as input the feed of the audio.

Is there anyone that has implemented this to share his knowledge.

Comment: You can directly stream the audio data from the microphone and use [SpeechClient](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.126.0/speech/v1/speechclient) in php to get the speech converted to text.Let me know if it’s helpful or not?

Comment: But on the SpeechClient I need to give a uri with the audio. But it will be streaming audio from users browser that I can transfer it with web socket. Then I suppose on the php I will have to grab the blob coming from the web socket and feed this to SpeechClient.

Comment: Hi @ToroLoco, Yes , you need to get the blob file from websocket and feed it into SpeechClient. You can try this [code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/main/Speech/src/SpeechClient.php) for your requirement. Let me know if it’s helpful or not?